# Function call by expression in angularJS ng event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem where I want to map buttons created with ng-repeat to certain functions in the controller. I am defining a string with the function name like this:

```
$scope.sections = [
{
    title: 'Music',
    desc: 'Some examples of electronic music I have produced using Fl Studio.',
    color: '#76a86f',
    icon: 'img/icon/music.png',
    onClick: 'clickMusic()'
}];
```

The function is defined like:

```
$scope.clickMusic = function() {
    hideAll();
    document.getElementById("musicContent").classList.remove("hide");
    document.getElementById("musicContent").classList.add("show");
};
```

And then try to map the function to a html button like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <div class="sectionThumbnail"">
        <button ng-click="section.onClick">
            <img ng-src="{{ section.icon }}" id="sectionnail_{{$index}}" ng-mouseover="sectionhoverIn($index)" ng-mouseleave="sectionhoverOut($index)"> 
        </button>
        <div class="sectionthumbnailInfo">
            <p class="sectiontitle">{{ section.title }}</p> 
            {{ section.desc }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when clicking the button, nothing happens. I know that the clickMusic() function works as intended once executed, since I use the same function for another button on the webpage. When directly referring to the clickMusic() function in the ng-click, like ng-click="clickMusic()", it also works. I get no error in the console either.

Is there any way to refer to functions from an array in this way, or do I have to create an additional function, which takes an index argument from the repeat and then map the index to the desired functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `onClick: 'clickMusic()'` to `onClick: clickMusic` (this way you store a reference to the function you want to call inside angular template) and then in ng-click simply call that funtion `<button ng-click="section.onClick()">`

Comment: Although this wasn't fully accurate in my case, since my function is defined as $scope.clickMusic(). I've posted my own answer based on yours, but if you edit your answer to fit this specific case I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mic4ael's suggestion. I managed to figure it out.

in the controller:

```
$scope.sections = [
{
    title: 'Music',
    desc: 'Some examples of electronic music I have produced using Fl Studio.',
    color: '#76a86f',
    icon: 'img/icon/music.png',
    onClick: $scope.clickMusic
}];
```

The $scope is there due to my function being defined as:

```
$scope.clickMusic = function() {
    hideAll();
    document.getElementById("musicContent").classList.remove("hide");
    document.getElementById("musicContent").classList.add("show");
};
```

And then, just as mic4ael suggested, in HTML:

```
<button ng-click="section.onClick()">
```